# Best practice for combining requests with possible different return types

Tags: ajax, json, events, data-structures, frameworks

### Background

I'm working on a web application utilizing AJAX to fetch content/data and what have you - nothing out of the ordinary.

On the server-side certain events can happen that the client-side JavaScript framework needs to be notified about and vice versa. These events are not always related to the users immediate actions. It is not an option to wait for the next page refresh to include them in the document or to stick them in some hidden fields because the user might never submit a form.

Right now it is design in such a way that events to and from the server are riding a long with the users requests. For instance if the user clicks a 'view details' link this would fire a request to the server to fetch some HTML or JSON with details about the clicked item. Along with this request or rather the response, a server-side (invoked) event will return with the content.

### Question/issue 1:

I'm unsure how to control the queue of events going to the server. They can ride along with user invoked events, but what if these does not occur, the events will get lost. I imagine having a timer setup up to send these events to the server in the case the user does not perform some action. What do you think?

### Question/issue 2:

With regards to the responds, some being requested as HTML some as JSON it is a bit tricky as I would have to somehow wrap al this data for allow for both formalized (and unrelated) events and perhaps HTML content, depending on the request, to return to the client. Any suggestions? anything I should be away about, for instance returning HTML content wrapped in a JSON bundle?

### Update:

Do you know of any framework that uses an approach like this, that I can look at for inspiration (that is a framework that wraps events/requests in a package along with data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am tackling a similar problem to yours at the moment.  On your first question, I was thinking of implementing some sort of timer on the client side that makes an asycnhronous call for the content on expiry.

On your second question, I normaly just return JSON representing the data I need, and then present it by manipulating the Document model.  I prefer to keep things consistent.

As for best practices, I cant say for sure that what I am doing is or complies to any best practice, but it works for our present requirement.

You might want to also consider the performance impact of having multiple clients making asynchrounous calls to your web server at regular intervals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by 'call for the content on expiry'? Do you have a ttl on some of the content displayed?

I guess being strict about only returning JSON will make it easier to work with, though sometimes it is more desirable to render HTML server-side.

Yes, some of the data in the app is for statistics only, so I figured that only a subset of users should be sending this data. This will reduce requests to the server quite a bit.

Comment: If you had to return both structured data (like JSON) along with rendered data (like HTML) how would you do it?

Comment: 'call for the content on expiry' - what I meant was that I'd set up a timer (like the jQuery timer plugin), and when the timer expires (i.e. hits 0), it will perform a web service call to get the data.

Comment: I suppose you could embed the html in the json object.  I havent tried this, but im sure it will work. eg:  { id : "1", someOtherData: "23", someContent:"<div><p>Hello World</p></div>" }